# How can a stochastic filter be forecasted?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, structural-change, filter

After the covid-19 lockdown, employment (and other economic indicators) were shocked. I want to model a recovery in employment levels. I used an AR(2) model of quarter-on-quarter (q/q) employment growth, which I used to forecast employment after 2020 Q3, by industry. However, the two autoregressive coefficients tended to be negative, so after the positive growth in 2020Q3 and 2020Q4, the growth after that was not high enough.

I'm not that experienced at time series analysis, so I haven't learnt about non-stationary analysis yet. I do want to try model an autoregression on the deviations from a stochastic filter of the log employment level, though. I know how to forecast a linear trendline, but I don't yet know how to forecast a stochastic filter.

> How can a stochastic filter be forecasted?

Comment: Does the last gradient merely get used?

Comment: Do you only have one data point per quarter, i e., 2-3 points during corona? From what you write, it sounds like you evaluate the predictive performance on a single number (Q3) while it's typical to wait for tens or hundreds before making conclusions about the model fit. That would also be true for evaluating whether negative AR(1) and AR(2) are a problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm working with quarterly data. So far, the dataset goes up to 2020Q3. Because 2020 Q3 and Q4 have positive growth in my AR(2) model, the negative coefficients give low or negative growth in 2021 Q1. I don't want that, as the employment trend should be recovering, like an impulse response. So, instead of looking at the (stationary) growth rate trend, my idea is to rather fit an autoregressive model on the log employment level deviations from the steady-state trend. This means, I have to forecast the steady-state trend. Should I just project the last gradient of the stochastic filter?

Comment: By "stochastic filter", do you mean the AR(1) and AR(2) coefficients? So that "stochastic gradient" is a trend in residuals from the ((log-)mean-)trend? And by impulse response (a term often related to time-frequency and filter theory), do you mean a broken line (change point)? In any case, I know of few models where you would question the model based on poor fits on just two out-of-sample data points. Perhaps because I'm mostly engaged in the analysis of very non-deterministic phenomena. I can think of solutions in the R packages `mcp` and `segmented`, if you're interested

Comment: No, a "stochastic filter" finds the trend. For example, the Hodrick-Prescott Filter. [Here are examples](https://www.aidanhorn.co.za/blog/graphs#h.waagbiogfjna) (the individual regions show it more clearly). I hadn't used the HP Filter before that project that I just linked. My idea was to use the gradient of the stochastic filter... use the last gradient, for the last point in time, then project that steady-state trend linearly. Then, I would want to do the autoregression on the residuals from the filter, and fit the AR forecast onto the linear projection.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Time Series Analysis (I just read the first two weeks of https://www.economodel.com/time-series-analysis-2019 ). I'm a microeconometrician. So, even though I think an "impulse response" is a good concept to use here, I don't have much experience. 
By "non-deterministic", do you mean you have to incorporate probabilities into everything?
Yes, I use R.

Comment: If my method idea can't be verified, I might link this question in my working paper, in the hopes that my method gets reviewed. It might be worth trying it out, publishing the working paper, just to show it. And then hopefully someone reviews it and comments on it. :)

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it all. I only know of solutions that model intercepts, slopes, quadratic trends, etc. Though for some link functions, this can give a more smooth appearance on the observed scale. I have developed the `mcp` package [more here](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/) which has been used to model Corona consequences before [papers here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=5590697509718421309&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en), but for your data, it may be an overly strong simplification?